# Which to use: « C'est / Il est loin d'être un génie de l'informatique »

Tags: pronoms

> **C'est** loin d'être un génie de l'informatique.
>
> [ou] : **Il est** loin d'être un génie de l'informatique.

I’m vacillating back and forth between « c'est » and « il est ». In the case of:

> **C'est** un génie de l'informatique.

Only « c'est » can work. On the other hand, in the case of:

> **Il est** loin d'être futé.

Only « il est » can work. The original sentence comprises these two different constructions, in a manner of speaking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both can be and are used.

> - Lorsque Zola donne le premier article de son feuilleton Revue dramatique au Bien public, **il est loin d'être un débutant en littérature**. (Bernard Dort)
> - Ce qui prouve suffisamment qu'**il est loin d'être un imbécile** et démontrerait davantage encore, s'il en était besoin, l'excellence du droit et de la politique française. (Jacques-André Bertrand)

*Il est loin d'être* is more literary/formal while *c'est loin d'être* is more casual and "modern".

Given the tone of *génie de l'informatique*, the sentence is likely casual so *c'est* would be the best choice.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely "C'est loin d'être un génie de l'informatique."

"Il est loin d'être un génie de l'informatique" sounds wrong, I don't have any rule to confort this opinion, it just doesn't fit.

Comment: Given the presence of the adjective "loin", I was under the impression that "il est" might be the correct one. Hmm, interesting. Merci.

Comment: Les deux formulations sont correctes.